# Cannot add link to repo method (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have ASP.NET Core website and .NET Core Class Library for repo methods.

I added reference to ASP.NET Core in Class Library.

In Class Library I have repo method

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ToSeeWeb.Models;
using ToSeeWeb.Controllers;

namespace ToSeeRepo.Repositories
{
    public class ExperienceRepository
    {
        private readonly ToSeeDBContext _context;

        public List<Experience> GetAllExperience() {
            return _context.Experience.ToList();
        }



    }
}
```

And in Controller in ASP.NET Core controller I need to adв link to this repo

So I trying to do it like this

```
private ExperienceRepository _exprepo = new ExperienceRepository();
```

But it don't see it.

Also I cannot add `using TooSeeRepo.Repositories`

How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

So I found problem solution.

I delete ClassLibrary from Solution and from folder. After that I restarted Visual Studio and added it again and linked with parent project.

After those steps, it working great.